# Python Pandas: read csv with N columns where N is specified in the some other column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataset which has the following header:

```
<id>  <timestamp>  <N>  <1>  <2> ... <N>
```

In this dataset, every row has a column "N", a number that determines how many columns that are numerically labeled after it. For example, I have a row like the following:

```
5 142323151.14 800 5.3564 5.4534 ... 7.4839 (800 columns after the 3rd column)
```

It is guaranteed that all rows have the same number of columns.

How can I read this CSV file with Pandas `read_csv` and label the columns currectly? Is it possible to be done in a single call? I am learning Pandas, so I wonder how Pandas can do a task that would require multiple lines of Python code to do.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
I tried

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', names=['id','timestamp','count',...],
                        delimiter=' ',
                        header=None)
```

and I don't know what to put in the ... part

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what was the result? If all rows have the same number of columns the read_csv function should be able to read in the data properly.

Comment: @Benjamin See my new edits.

Comment: If you don't know ahead of time how many columns you have then just name the columns in the next line of code after you have read in the dataframe.

Comment: You don't need to indicate the column names or the number of columns as @ashishsingal has pointed out. You only need to specify the separator  `sep = ...` if the seperator in the csv file is not a comma (,). For example:  `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep = ';') `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

> What if I have several trailing columns, such as   
>   <1> <2> ...   , how do you use the value of n here?

```
In [320]: df
Out[320]:
   0             1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10    11    12
0   5  1.423232e+08   8   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  1000  1000
1   6  1.423236e+08   8  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  1000  1000

In [321]: ['id', 'timestamp', 'n'] + (df.columns[3:3+df.iat[0, 2]] - 2).tolist() + [11, 12]
Out[321]: ['id', 'timestamp', 'n', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12]

In [322]: df.columns = ['id', 'timestamp', 'n'] + (df.columns[3:3+df.iat[0, 2]] - 2).tolist() + [11, 12]

In [323]: df
Out[323]:
   id     timestamp  n   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    11    12
0   5  1.423232e+08  8   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  1000  1000
1   6  1.423236e+08  8  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  1000  1000
```

if you can predefine trailing column names, you can do this:

```
In [328]: trailing_cols = ['max','min']

In [329]: ['id', 'timestamp', 'n'] + (df.columns[3:3+df.iat[0, 2]] - 2).tolist() + trailing_cols
Out[329]: ['id', 'timestamp', 'n', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'max', 'min']
```

**OLD answer:**

I'd do it this way:

first read your CSV not specifying column names:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

In [271]: df
Out[271]:
   0             1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   5  1.423232e+08  800   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
1   5  1.423232e+08  800  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88
```

now we can rename columns as follows:

```
In [272]: df.columns = ['id', 'timestamp', 'n'] + (df.columns[3:].values - 2).tolist()

In [273]: df
Out[273]:
   id     timestamp    n   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0   5  1.423232e+08  800   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
1   5  1.423232e+08  800  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88
```

Comment: What if I have several trailing columns, such as `<id>  <timestamp>  <N>  <1>  <2> ... <N>  <max> <min>`, how do you use the value of `n` here?

Comment: @zkytony, how do you want to name the trailing columns - `('max','min')`? Are those names predefined?

Comment: so when parsing the rows, we assume that the last column means 'min' and the second-to-last one means 'max'. They will not be part of the numerically indexed columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the number of columns in read_csv. You can just call

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

And it should read all the columns in (and rows as well). You can pass `header=0` if you'd like but pandas can usually infer this.

Comment: In the raw csv data, there is no header row. If I want to call the column with value <N> (e.g. `800`) the name "count", how do I specify the column name for the N columns after it?